# How do I find the version number in a string in a cmd script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For my software development project, I am using .cmd files to automatically create binaries with the version number in the file name. The version number is stored in a C header file.

I have a file called "app_version.h" which contains something like

```
Generic include file code or commenting
#define APP_SW_VER ("Vx.y.zww")
More generic include file code or commenting
```

Where `Vx.y.zww` is the format for the version number. Valid examples are:

- `V1.0.1`
- `V1.0.1DBG`
- `V1.0.1PT11`
- `V81.2.1RC2`

As for the file name, I want to replace the dots with underscores and append it to a predefined string and then use that as a file name.

**Prime problem:** To extract the `Vx.y.zww` part and use it as a variable in a cmd file.

**Example of the whole procedure**

Inputs:

"MYPROGRAM" as predefined string

Binary filed called "output.bin"

File app_version.h contains the line `#define APP_SW_VER ("V1.1.3")`

Desired output:

File with name "MYPROGRAM_V1_1_3.bin"

Comment: Regular expressions can be used

Comment: @LearningPhase Do you have an example? I am able to use findstr and regular expressions to find the correct line in app_version.h, but I don't understand how to extract that specific part, nor how to store it as a variable.

Comment: Hereby a link, which explains some string manipulations, to be used in batchfiles: https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quite straight forward (theoretical - see note below): get the correct line and get the part between the quotes. Replace `.` with `_` and add your predefined string and the extension:

```
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^" %%a in ('type app_version.h^|findstr /bc:"#define APP_SW_VER"') do set "ver=%%a"
echo MYPROGRAM_%ver:.=_%.bin
```

Note: the usual syntax `for /f "tokens=2 delims=x"` can't be used for a delimiter `"`. Therefore we have to use this ugly workaround (without surrounding quotes, but escaping some special chars instead).

Another possibility (thanks, Squashman) is to use `()` as delimiters. The quotes can easily removed by using `%%~a` (can keep the familiar syntax):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%a in ('type app_version.h^|findstr /bc:"#define APP_SW_VER"') do set "ver=%%~a"
echo MYPROGRAM_%ver:.=_%.bin
```

Comment: You could also use the `()` as the delimiters and then used the `~` to remove the quotes.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks. I see a lot of batch scripts doing string manipulation with for-loops, is this a shortcoming in what the language can do, or is it perfectably reasonable?

Comment: well, in batch [substring manipulation](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) is a bit basic (as most other concepts). Keep in mind, it's not a programming language but basically simple commands made scriptable. I'd say, it's "reasonable within its limitations"

Comment: @AudunKnudsroed, I don't think it was Microsoft's intention to really do any type of string or data manipulation with batch files.  It was more meant for command and control similar to what JCL does on mainframes.  So eventually they created Vbscript and Jscript and now Powershell.  All three of them have infinitely more possibilities with data manipulation.